# Why compiler thinks two empty classes are different?

Tags: c#

Why compiler thinks these two classes are different?

```
public class A()
{
}

public class B()
{
}
```

I think this question is really ridiculous. but I wonder what is the core reason why compiler determine they are different. Is there someone who can tell me what's happening in the back side of compiler.

Thank you.

Comment: Twin brothers are different, they have different names

Comment: @Cleptus I wanted to know what makes them different in a computer. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *name* of the class is the primary identifier that is used to discern the different between types, that is why within a given namespace, you cannot have duplicate class names.

> The hint is that it is called a *name* space, within a given *space* all the classes will have unique names.

Perhaps a better question is why you think a class with a name/id of `A` is somehow able to be confused with another class that has an name/id of `B`?

Answer (score 5):

The concept here is "structural type equivalence" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) . Some languages consider two types to be equal if they are "structurally" equal - that is, if they have the same members.

JScript uses structural equivalence.

C# / C++ / Java do not - just because two types have the same shape does not make them equivalent.   Some reasons as to the benefits of strong typing over structural equivalence:

1. This can be useful for strong type checking and ensuring that types don't get accidentally assigned to each other just because they coincidentally have the same shape.
2. "same shape" can be more difficult to determine once you have private members and polymorphism in the picture.
3. It allow significant optimizations for execution.